# how i can make the result show when click on select without button and display on text box

Tags: javascript, html, css, forms

,
i want the output like this picture
i don't know how the result display in text box ,and on select the  temperature.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/47Vjc.png)

`

Temperature Converter
    
       
        body {
            font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
            text-align: center;
            margin: 30px;
            border-width: 12cap;
            border-color: black;
        }

```
    label {
        display:ruby-base;
        margin-bottom: 10px;
    }

    input {
        padding: 10px;
        margin: 20px;
    }

    button {
        padding: 10px;
       
        border: none;
        border-radius: 5px;
        cursor: pointer;
    }

    #result {
        font-size: 18px;
        margin-top: 20px;
    }
</style>
```

```
<h2>Temperature Converter</h2>

<label for="temperature">Temperature:</label>
<input type="text" id="temperature" placeholder="Temperature">
<br></br>



<select id="unit">
    <option value="celsius">C</option>
    <option value="fahrenheit">F</option>
</select><br></br>


<br></br>

<div id="result"></div>

<script>
    function convertTemperature() {
        // Get input values
        var temperature = parseFloat(document.getElementById('temperature').value);
        var unit = document.getElementById('unit').value;

        // Check if the input is a valid number
        if (isNaN(temperature)) {
            alert("Please enter a valid temperature!");
            return;
        }

        // Convert temperature based on the selected unit
        var result;
        if (unit === 'celsius') {
            result = (temperature * 9/5) + 32;
            document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = temperature  + result.toFixed(2) ;
        } else {
            result = (temperature - 32) * 5/9;
            document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = temperature  + result.toFixed(2) ;
        }
    }
</script>
```

`
pleas help me with this
i can't find the answer

Comment: Didn't understand very well your question, you want to calculate the temperature depends if the user selects farenheit or celsius without adding a "Calculate button"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

hello my friend your UI is little confusing because when you want convert sth to sth it is better for your user to konw which unit is converted to another unit. so it better to write in option tag sth like this "c => f" or "f => c".

must easiest way to show the result is to add eventListener to your (id ="temperature") with change value. like below

```
enter code here
document.getElementById('temperature').addEventListener('change', convertTemperature);
```

and you can update your result at the end of you "temperature" function like this

```
enter code here
if (unit === 'celsius') {
        let farenhite = (temperature * 9/5) + 32;
        result = Number(temperature).toFixed(2) + Number(farenhite).toFixed
        document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = Number(result).toFixed(2) ;
    } else {
        let celsius = (temperature - 32) * 5/9;
        result = Number(temperature).toFixed(2) + Number(celsius).toFixed;
        document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = Number(result).toFixed(2);
    }
```

after this your decimal in the result will fix with two place.

Answer (score 1):

Add event listeners to your input and dropdown that will call your function.

```js
document.getElementById('temperature').addEventListener('input', convertTemperature);
document.getElementById('unit').addEventListener('change', convertTemperature);
```

Answer (score 0):

You have defined a function `convertTemperature()` but never called it.

You can create a button with `onclick` attribute set to `convertTemperature()` so that, that function is called when you click on that button.

It will look something like this -

```js
function convertTemperature() {
        // Get input values
        var temperature = parseFloat(document.getElementById('temperature').value);
        var unit = document.getElementById('unit').value;

        // Check if the input is a valid number
        if (isNaN(temperature)) {
            alert("Please enter a valid temperature!");
            return;
        }

        // Convert temperature based on the selected unit
        var result;
        if (unit === 'celsius') {
            result = (temperature * 9/5) + 32;
            document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = temperature  + result.toFixed(2) ;
        } else {
            result = (temperature - 32) * 5/9;
            document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = temperature  + result.toFixed(2) ;
        }
    }
```

```html
    <body>
        
        
        <h2>Temperature Converter</h2>
        
        <label for="temperature">Temperature:</label>
        <input type="text" id="temperature" placeholder="Temperature">
        <br></br>
        
        
        
        <select id="unit">
            <option value="celsius">C</option>
            <option value="fahrenheit">F</option>
        </select><br></br>
        
        
        <br></br>
        
        <div id="result"></div>
        <button onclick="convertTemperature()">submit</button>
    </body>
```

Comment: Welcome SO @prajwal :) Nice, but I'd prefer `onChange` instead of `onClick` :)

Answer (score 0):

You just need to call the function on your input and select element, try to replace your code like this,
`<select id="unit" onchange="convertTemperature()">` and also on your input component `<input type="text" id="temperature" placeholder="Temperature" onkeypress="convertTemperature()">`